# Save a entry in a table and a relationned entry in other at the same time?

Tags: symfony1

I have a Product table with a field to store the price. 
Each time, this price was changing, i need te keep the ancient value. So I have created a table called History to store the product id, the price and the date of changing.
I've also created this method in my product class to generate a new entry :

```
public function updateHistory($modified) {      
    if(array_key_exists('price', $modified)) {
        $history = new History()
        $history = new History();$
        $history->setProductId($this->getId());
        $history->setPrice($modified['price']);
        $history->save()
    }
}
```

I call this method from the presave() method

```
public function preSave($event) {
    $modified = $this->getModified();
    $this->updateHistory($modified);
}
```

It works fine for edited product but not at all for a new product because it has no id at this time (product id is null in history table) and if i use updateHistory method in the postSave method, $modified is null;

So how can i create my first entry in the history table for a new product ?

Thanks all for you response and the time passed to help me !

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to easily keep track of the history of a product, you can use the "[Versionable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors%3Acore-behaviors%3Aversionable/en)" behavior in your schema.yml file. This, way you will have an history with very few coding involved.